# Is there a closed form for sum of chooses?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a closed form for $\sum_{i=a}^{b}\frac{{{i} \choose{n}}^2}{i}$?

Comment: Very probably not! You didnt give ranges for $a,b$?

Comment: Although it will seem like a bit of an artifice, this can be expressed in terms of a generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: It is very clear what is being asked, and whuber, an O(200k) score top-scorer here has given a hint of the right direction for the answer.  I also agree with the implication of his hint, instead of his typical (amazing, detailed, and beautiful) answers, that this "smells" like homework so a self-study tag might be in order.

Answer (score 1):

**This is already closed-form (in a certain sense):** What you have given is a finite sum, where each terms in the sum is given by a finite number of arithmetic operations.  Assuming you have $n \leqslant a \leqslant b$, you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
S(n,a,b) \equiv \sum_{i=a}^b \frac{1}{i} {i \choose n}^2
&= \sum_{i=a}^b \frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{i!}{n!(n-i)!} \cdot \frac{i!}{n!(n-i)!}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Each factorial is a finite product of integers, and so each term in the sum can be obtained with a finite number of arithmetic operations on the integers.  Since your function is a finite sum of these terms, it can be calculated in a finite number of arithmetic operations.  Hence, it is already written as a [closed-form expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression), or what [Chow (1999)](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf) calls an "elementary function".

From the comments below this answer (between [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber) and I) you will see that there are some different ideas of the meaning of "closed form".  I have interpreted this in the above sense.  If you meant it in some other way, then this would lead to a different answer.

Comment: By "closed form" people usually mean that the amount of computation is $O(1)$--that is, it does not grow unbounded as $|b-a|$ grows.  The concept is a little slippery and can be defined in various ways depending on your model of computation and what you consider to be the cost of an operation.

Comment: I have not heard of that definition of closed-form.  Do you have a link to that definition and its context?

Comment: I don't know of any formal definition in mathematics, because "closed form" seems to be a sort of meta-mathematical, folklorish concept.  I think, though, that the onus is on you here to provide a definition (and perhaps even a reference) that accords with your (rather surprising) statement that in effect all sums that are not explicitly infinite are in closed form.  That is contrary to all uses of the term I have encountered.

Comment: I was going by the (linked) definition in Wikipedia, which seems to be the "second approach" mentioned in [Borwein and Crandall (2013)](http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/201301/rnoti-p50.pdf), and also consistent with the notion of an "elementary function" in [Chow (1999)](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf) (p. 441).  I've had the opposite experience to you - I've only heard of closed-form in these senses, and have never heard of it as a computational-order property!  So as far as I've ever heard it, every finite sum of closed-form expressions is a closed-form expression.

Comment: Anyway, it's useful to see that there is a lot of difference in meaning floating around out there!  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I recall seeing Chow, or something like it. However, I think none of these references get to the heart of the present matter, which is whether one ought to consider a finite *but indefinite* number of operations *with no upper bound* as a "closed form." (The fact the OP asks this question indicates s/he doesn't view it as closed.) Not imposing a fixed upper bound seems just as (or even more) dissatisfying as living with "$x$ is a solution to $x+e^x=0.$"  I would agree that an expression like $\sum_{i=1}^{10^{99}}1/i$ is "closed," despite having some qualms even about that one.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the issue.  I suppose the way I look at it is that, regardless of how big $b$ is, we still have a finite computation, though the number of operations might balloon with $b$.  I agree that we can still have qualms about the practicability of computing it (along the lines of your sum of $10^{99}$ terms), but I take "closure" to refer to the weaker requirement of an expression being closed under finite application of some operations.  I guess I don't see "closed form" as implying ease of computation, so I have less qualms with that kind of talk.

Comment: Thank you, Ben, for taking the time to explain your answer (+1).